# Inner Join table onto its self after grouping the table

Tags: php, mysql

I have producing the following query to search a table and return back only the multiple occurrences like so (max occurrence is two times never more):

```
SELECT * FROM spin
            WHERE `serial` in (
            SELECT `serial` from spin group by `serial`
            HAVING count(*) > 1
            ) ORDER BY test_started DESC
```

In this table each record has a test_started column, I'm then looping over the results set like so:

```
<?php foreach ($tests as $test) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php if (isset($test->model)) echo $test->model; ?></td>
<td><?php if (isset($test->serial)) echo $test->serial; ?></td>
<td><?php if (isset($test->error_count)) echo $test->error_count; ?></td>
<td><?php if (isset($test->max_temp)) $test_temp = substr($test->max_temp, -2); echo $test_temp; ?></td>
<td><?php if (isset($test->test_started)) echo $test->test_started; ?></td>
<td><?php if (isset($test->test_ended)) echo $test->test_ended; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

What I would like to do is group the matching serials into one column, I'm guessing some kind of DISTINCT query is needed for this and then show both the first and second test_started dates

Comment: just to verify the obvious first - but 'serial' is just a placeholder value for your actual values? Or is it indeed an actual value?

Comment: serial is a column in the table spin table

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen What's your point? I don't follow.

Comment: @twigg If it was me, I'd forget about all the PHP stuff for the time being. Just provide proper DDLs and a desired result.

Comment: @Strawberry the point is that 'serial' is a string literal in sql.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen 'serial' may be. But \`serial\` is not. (love your punditry BTW ;-) )

Comment: Ahh - just saw it colored in the text, so hadn't noticed the difference between ' and `. Subtle but important.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want a maximum of 2 counts of `serials` that are the same and you want the first and start date, so here's a try:

```
SELECT A.model, A.`serial`, A.error_count, A.max_temp, A.test_started, B.test_ended
 FROM ( 
  SELECT model, `serial`, error_count, max_temp, test_started 
  FROM spin 
  WHERE `serial` in (
    SELECT `serial` from spin group by `serial`
    HAVING count(*) = 2
    ) 
    GROUP BY `serial`, test_started ASC
 ) A
 INNER JOIN
 (
  SELECT model, `serial`, error_count, max_temp, test_started as test_ended
  FROM spin 
  WHERE `serial` in (
    SELECT `serial` from spin group by `serial`
    HAVING count(*) = 2
    ) 
  GROUP BY `serial`, test_started DESC
  ) B
  ON A.`serial` = B.`serial`
  GROUP BY A.`serial
```

See <kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31c5e2/1)</kbd>